# How to list files in "autoload" directory?

Tags: autoload

I use some statusline plugin, which source theme files from `<the-autoload-directory>/lightline/colorscheme/*.vim`.

Many color plugins also provide themes for that statusline. Switching the theme requires just one argument, the theme name, which is same as its file name. So I would like to get the list of available themes, i.e. list of files at that path. Putting the list at current cursor position would be good enough.

Closest command is `:runtime lightline/or/smth/*.vim` which would execute files rather than list them.

For the plain colorschemes the list is generated on `:colo <tab>` , though I don't know how it does its job..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:h glob()`

And for your case it might be:

```
:echo glob("~/.vim/**/lightline/**/*.vim")
```

Comment: thanx, it did the job

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`globpath()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#globpath%28%29) instead of `glob()` as you seems to be interested in all autoload directories.

```
echo globpath(&rtp, 'autoload/**/lightline/**/*.vim')
```

Internally, Vim also uses the [`'runtimepath'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27runtimepath%27) to search for files with all these commands.

Note: if you want to do something programmatically with it, set `{list}` parameter to 1 in order to obtain a [`List`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#List)

```
echo globpath(&rtp, 'autoload/**/lightline/**/*.vim', 0, 1)
```